# Grid Template Not Snappable in Fireworks CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-fireworks, grids, snapping

I've seen many blogs highly recommend using a grid like 960 for prototyping in newer version of Fireworks.

I'm using CS6.

When I create a new fireworks document from template, I select the Grid12.png, 960.png, etc. When I try to add objects to another layer, they are not snapping to the guides or the vertical grid paths. I've enabled snap to grid, guide, smart guide, 9-slice scaling, etc.

I would assume that most people would want the ability to snap to these guides. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

When you open one of the grids system template, the layers are setup in this order:

- Baseline Grid
- Sidebars
- Columns

The blue color guidelines are actually lines drawn in the Baseline Grid layer.  They are not the Guides.  So any layer objects you move near them, it will not snap.  They are just visual guides use for align vertical spacing of elements. We only turn it on when we need it and so it is done this way to separate from the guides.

The actual snapping behavior, is on the column guides.  These are the Guides.  You can turn it on or off by pressing cmd+; You can also go to the View menu, Guides > Show Guides to turn it on.  Your object should be able to snap to them if you turn on the "Show Guides" option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Fireworks user but, I think I understand your issue. What you are trying to snap to isn't a guide or another object but color areas within an image.

If you are snapping to pixels and your grid images are sized and placed correctly, you'll be able to see if you are on the grid but it won't automatically snap unless you make guides on top of it manually.

The nice thing about those grid images is that you can overlay them on your pages after the code is built to see how accurately your CSS is rendering. There is a plug-in for Firefox to do this on the fly or you can actually code it into the page for testing with an opacity value.